# LWC test async call from button click

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I have a custom lightning web component that I want to pass tests but I'm not being able to accomplish with an async call fired from a button click.

html

```
<lightning-button label="Validate" slot="footer" class="custom-validate-button" data-action="validate" onclick={handleValidate} disabled={isLoading} icon-name="utility:rating"></lightning-button>
```

js

```
handleValidate(){
    this.isLoading = true;
    isContactGood().then(data => {
        this.showToast({
            variant : data ? 'success' : 'error',
            message : data ? this.successMessage : this.errorMessage
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        this.handleExceptionMessage(error);
    }).finally(() => {
        this.isLoading = false
    });
}
```

This `isContactGood` only returns true or false.

test.js

```
jest.mock(
'@salesforce/apex/MyLwcController.isContactGood',
() => {
    return{
        default: jest.fn()
    };
},
{ virtual : true }
)

it('validate contact', async() => {
    const element = createElement('c-my-lwc', {
        is : MyLwc,
    });
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    const content = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('[data-action=validate]');
    
    isContactGood.mockResolvedValue(true);

    await content.click();
    expect(isContactGood).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(isContactGood).toHaveReturnedWith(true);
});
```

And this is the result

```
Expected: true
Received: {}
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?